# Oracle Object Relational DB ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the names of all customers who have more than 3 projects and the count of their projects but I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 32
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I understand that I have to include everything in the GROUP BY but I kinda did.

customer_t and staff_t are inheriting from user_t.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(TREAT(REF(u) AS REF customer_t).name.first_name, ' '), (TREAT(REF(u) AS REF customer_t).name.last_name)) AS name, COUNT(p.projectno)
FROM "USER" u JOIN project p ON u.idno = p.customer.idno
WHERE VALUE(u) IS OF TYPE (customer_t)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(p.projectno) > 3;
```

```
CREATE TYPE name_t AS OBJECT (
  first_name     VARCHAR2(32),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(32)
);

CREATE TYPE address_t AS OBJECT (
  province       VARCHAR2(32),
  street         VARCHAR2(32),
  city           VARCHAR2(32),
  postal_code    VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TYPE user_t AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  email          VARCHAR2(40),
  password       VARCHAR2(32),
  name           name_t,
  address        address_t,
  phone          VARCHAR2(15),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE rank_t AS OBJECT (
  rankno       NUMBER,
  name         VARCHAR2(40),
  description  VARCHAR2(60)
);

CREATE TABLE "RANK" OF rank_t (
  PRIMARY KEY (rankno),
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TYPE customer_t UNDER user_t (

);

CREATE TYPE staff_t UNDER user_t (
  salary       NUMBER(7,2),
  rank         REF rank_t
);

CREATE TABLE "USER" OF user_t (
  PRIMARY KEY (idno),
  UNIQUE (email));

CREATE TYPE project_t AS OBJECT (
  projectno    NUMBER,
  name         VARCHAR2(40),
  description  VARCHAR2(60),
  customer     REF customer_t,
  service      REF service_t
);

CREATE TABLE project OF project_t (PRIMARY KEY (projectno));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(TREAT(REF(u) AS REF customer_t).name.first_name, ' '), (TREAT(REF(u) AS REF customer_t).name.last_name)) AS name, 
COUNT(p.projectno)
FROM "USER" u JOIN project p ON u.idno = p.customer.idno
WHERE VALUE(u) IS OF TYPE (customer_t)
GROUP BY CONCAT(CONCAT(TREAT(REF(u) AS REF customer_t).name.first_name, ' '), (TREAT(REF(u) AS REF customer_t).name.last_name)) 
HAVING COUNT(p.projectno) > 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just found it myself as well after 20 minutes struggling.